# Move row(s) at indexPath with animation

Tags: ios, uikit

Is it possible to reorder MULTIPLE rows in UITableView with an animation. Ideally the expected output would be something similar to the Reminders app on MacOS. I've included a screen shot below. But say you have a table view with A, B , C, D. I would like to select A, B and move them with an animation to the end of the list so the end result is C, D, A, B.

In the example documentation from Apple for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614987-moverow it says:

"
If you want multiple rows moved, you can call this method repeatedly within a beginUpdates()–endUpdates() block.
"

Was wondering if anyone had any example code around this or has successfully been able to do get my desired result:

[Example of drag multiple rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiazt.png)

Comment: If you use a diffable data source this is trivial to do. But otherwise the perform batch updates approach is correct. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: Or do you mean letting the USER drag multiple rows?  In that case, I don’t think you can.

Comment: inside a UIView.animateWithDuration method block call moveRow method  and after  TableView EndUpdates method call self.view.layoutIfNeeded method.

Comment: @matt Yes that is precisely what I am looking for. I want the user to essentially tap: Edit -> Select the cells they want to move -> Drag a single reorder handle and move all the rows by dragging and dropping.

Comment: @Help Have you tried that before? I don't see how that would work given that UIView.animateWithDuration is a blocking linear animation. Wouldn't give the drag effect I am looking for.

Comment: @matt I am trying to find a nice example of how to due such a task but couldn't find one online. So I asked here. I will keep searching and post an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: There is no built in way to do that in iOS and I would recommend abandoning the idea.